# Update Distributed Cache Size - Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, distributedcache, size

I'm trying to update the size of Distribute cache but keep getting the below error:

> "set-cachehostconfig : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + set-cachehostconfig -CacheSize 1228 -cacheport 22233 -hostname usa0300vm1160
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AFCacheHostConfiguration]
>      , NullReferenceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Applicat
>      ionServer.Caching.Commands.SetAFCacheHostConfigurationCommand"**

Distributed cache is running on only one server(out of 3).

I even tried `Update-SPDistributedCacheSize`  but get the same error.

Comment: did you try this http://blogs.technet.com/b/sp/archive/2013/05/29/calculate-and-set-distributed-cache-size.aspx

Comment: check this too http://nikpatel.net/2013/09/26/adjust-cache-size-of-the-sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-service-part-iii-using-set-update-spdistributedcachesize-command/

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan I use the same command and approach as described in both articles but get only error message

Comment: Are you running this on a host with DC deployed? Do you have >1 DC server, if so, drop down to one before running the cmdlet.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Yes,I'm running on a host with DC deployed and i have only one server where DC is enabled. Even on a standalone Dev machine,I get this error while updating the cache size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of tries,I finally updated the Distributed Cache size.

I used the following commands multiple times in the same order: Give 2 minutes gap between `Remove` and `Add` commands

```
Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance -Graceful

$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService" 
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername} 
$serviceInstance.delete()

Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance

Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance 

Update-SPDistributedCacheSize
```